# How can I move the object down with three.js?

Tags: three.js, position

Recently I've seen a example of three.js: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals
I've changed the obj myself, but I'm not familiar with webGL or three.js, I don't know how I can move the object a little down(see the image). I've read the documentation of three.js and tried to change some arguments which I suppose it can move the object down, I'm a new guy in three.js and WebGL.

[how can I move the figure down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tI8L.jpg)

Comment: did u figure out how to do it? i am loading a `gltf` or `glb` file, but have no clue how to access the model itself

Answer (score 0):

Your object has an attribute named 'position', it shows how to place your object in the space, the type of 'position' is `THREE.Vector3` which has 3 dimensions x, y and z. so you can use these simple code to move your object:

```
yourobjcet.position.x+=somevaluex;
yourobjcet.position.y+=somevaluey;
yourobjcet.position.z+=somevaluez;

//or, use built-in function 
yourobject.translateY(somevalue);
```

You just need to make your object's position y down.

Or, if you just want to center your object, you could use `yourobject.geometry.center()`.

Comment: Seems that the topic starter just wants to center the model, Thus maybe it would be easier to use `.center()`, a method of `THREE.Geometry()` or `THREE.BufferGeometry()`.

Comment: and how do you access `yourobject` if youre using `loader.load` to import a `gltf` or `glb` file?